# Where is my mistake selecting coalesce mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a column `discount_amount`, if there's no `SUM(discount_amount)` (`NULL`) THEN it's zero (0).

I wrote the query with this

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(discount_amount) 
FROM order_discount
WHERE order_discount.discount_type_id = 6
  AND order_discount.order_match_id = om1.id, 0);
```

but I get an error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM order_discount WHERE order_discount.discou' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(discount_amount), 0)
FROM order_discount
WHERE order_discount.discount_type_id = 6 AND order_discount.order_match_id = om1.id;
```

This has to be part of bigger query, where derive table `om1` is defined somehow.

Alternatively, you can `COALESCE()` the result of the subquery like this:

```
COALESCE(
    (
        SELECT SUM(discount_amount) 
        FROM order_discount
        WHERE order_discount.discount_type_id = 6 AND order_discount.order_match_id = om1.id
    ),
    0
)
```

Again, this only makes sense if included in a bigger query.

Comment: both of them will produce the same result that i want, or it's different result?

Comment: @FachryDzaky: both give the same result. But you would incorporate them differently in your entire query (which you did not show).